# sum of array elements using recursion

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int getSum(int *arr, int size) {
    if(size == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(size == 1 )
    {
        return arr[0];
    }
    int remainingPart = getSum(arr+1, size-1);
    int sum = arr[0] + remainingPart;
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int arr[100], n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> arr[n];
    }
    int sum = getSum(arr, n);
    cout << "Sum is " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3
1
2
3
Sum is -1827678256
```

When i run the code with custom input it gives the correct output. But when i input data from the user it gives an incorrect answer. Why so?

Comment: The loop keeps the array elements unitialized.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean with "custom input" and "input from the user"? What is the difference?

Comment: Side note: You might want some extra checking when you get the value of `n` to ensure the user doesn't request for more numbers than `arr` can hold.

Comment: From a *recursion* standpoint, the implementation cannot be optimized using tail recursion optimization (TRO) — it doesn't fulfill the TRO constraints.  (Probably not important, because I've only run across a few C++ compilers that support tail recursion optimization.)  Without TRO, there is a distinct possibility of incurring a *stack overflow* for a large enough array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cin >> arr[n];
```

should be

```
cin >> arr[i];
```